# kendo timezone directive in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler, kendo-timepicker

I want to select kendo timezone by dropdownlist.I have search kendo-timezone directive in angularjs but i have not found.I want to kendo timezone directive like that "kendo-date-picker(this is timepicker directive in angularjs)".If you have any idea please share me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problems like that

```
    <div kendo-timezone-editor ng-model="dataItem.eventTimezone"></div>
```